# python scrapy can't see scraped data on console

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy, web-crawler

Hi When i run my spider i am not able to see any scrapped data in my console.
here is my spider.

```
import scrapy

class HackaholicSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "hackaholic"

    def start_request(self):
        urls = ['http://hackaholic.info']
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        for article in response.xpath('//article'):
            yield {
                    'title': article.xpath("//h2[@class='entry-title']/a/text()").extract(),
                    'published_date': article.xpath("//div[@class='entry-meta']/span/time[@class='onDate date published']/a/text()").extract()
                   }
```

I am trying to extract article title and date published.

When I run my spider:

```
juniour@hackaholic:~/git/scrapy/tutorial$ scrapy crawl hackaholic
2018-09-27 17:43:07 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.5.1 started (bot: tutorial)
2018-09-27 17:43:07 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.2.1.0, libxml2 2.9.4, cssselect 1.0.3, parsel 1.5.0, w3lib 1.19.0, Twisted 18.7.0, Python 3.6.6 (default, Sep 12 2018, 18:26:19) - [GCC 8.0.1 20180414 (experimental) [trunk revision 259383]], pyOpenSSL 17.5.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.0g  2 Nov 2017), cryptography 2.1.4, Platform Linux-4.15.0-34-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-18.04-bionic
2018-09-27 17:43:07 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'BOT_NAME': 'tutorial', 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'tutorial.spiders', 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['tutorial.spiders']}
2018-09-27 17:43:07 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2018-09-27 17:43:07 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2018-09-27 17:43:07 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2018-09-27 17:43:07 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2018-09-27 17:43:07 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2018-09-27 17:43:07 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2018-09-27 17:43:07 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6024
2018-09-27 17:43:07 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2018-09-27 17:43:07 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 27, 12, 13, 7, 699046),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 1,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'memusage/max': 51904512,
 'memusage/startup': 51904512,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 27, 12, 13, 7, 696301)}
2018-09-27 17:43:07 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to rename the `start_request` method to `start_requests`, which is the method that you have to override from the base `Spider` class. More info [here](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.start_requests).

What's happening is that your spider is not issuing any requests because of the missing `start_requests` method.

This is how it is supposed to be:

```
import scrapy

class HackaholicSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "hackaholic"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = ['http://hackaholic.info']
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    ...
```

Comment: There is also a type in the `for` loop. You wrote **artile** instead of **article**